# Simplifying a trait method with too many arguments?

Tags: design-patterns, rust, traits

I have a trait, which defines several functions. One of these functions has too many arguments. It also is a default implementation and inside, it makes calls to other trait functions via `self`. My question is how do I reduce the number of arguments to the function without going into massive refactoring?

My first instinct was to go with a builder pattern. I would define a new struct that would contain all the arguments to the function. With this, I would modify the default trait implementation to instead return a builder object and then have the user supply the arguments to the builder. Finally, the actual implementation code would then go in to some `.build()` or execute function.

The problem with that approach is that the default implementation uses `self`. This means that I need to have the build function take the trait as an argument, something like `fn build(&self, &impl MyTrait) -> Result<>`. I don't like this because this is kinda ugly:

```
let res = something.handle()
              .withArg1(...)
              .withArg2(...)
              .build(something);
```

What better ways can I simplify this?

Comment: "The problem with that approach is that the default implementation uses `self`" - what's wrong with borrowing it in the builder, then?

Comment: You need to show more code to understand your problem better. At least show us your before/after function signature, otherwise I don't know what to answer, I can't optimize code I don't have :) I think which pattern to pick strongly depends on what the function actually does.

Answer (score 1):

As @Cerberus points out, you can store a reference to the caller inside your builder struct. Alternatively, you could write the method to take a struct containing all the arguments. I have sketched out both possibilities on [the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=12d96b042fc9a547a12532fe7a0941fb) but will enclose it here too:

```
trait MyTrait {
    fn handle_with_too_many_args(&self, arg1: u32, arg2: u32, arg3: u32) -> u32 {
        arg1 * arg2 * arg3
    }
    
    fn handle_with_struct(&self, args: HandleArgs) -> u32 {
        self.handle_with_too_many_args(args.arg1, args.arg2, args.arg3)
    }
    
    fn handle_with_builder(&self) -> Handle<'_, Self> {
        Handle::new(self)
    }
}

struct HandleArgs {
    arg1: u32,
    arg2: u32,
    arg3: u32,
}

impl HandleArgs {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            arg1: 1, // set sensible defaults here
            arg2: 2,
            arg3: 3,
        }
    }
    
    fn with_arg1(mut self, arg1: u32) -> Self {
        self.arg1 = arg1;
        self
    }
    
    fn with_arg2(mut self, arg2: u32) -> Self {
        self.arg2 = arg2;
        self
    }

    fn with_arg3(mut self, arg3: u32) -> Self {
        self.arg3 = arg3;
        self
    }
}

struct Handle<'handler, T: MyTrait + ?Sized> {
    handler: &'handler T,
    arg1: u32,
    arg2: u32,
    arg3: u32,
}

impl<'handler, T: MyTrait + ?Sized> Handle<'handler, T> {
    fn new(handler: &'handler T) -> Self {
        Self {
            handler,
            arg1: 1, // set sensible defaults here
            arg2: 2,
            arg3: 3,
        }
    }
    
    fn with_arg1(mut self, arg1: u32) -> Self {
        self.arg1 = arg1;
        self
    }

    fn with_arg2(mut self, arg2: u32) -> Self {
        self.arg2 = arg2;
        self
    }

    fn with_arg3(mut self, arg3: u32) -> Self {
        self.arg3 = arg3;
        self
    }
    
    fn finish(self) -> u32 {
        self.handler.handle_with_too_many_args(self.arg1, self.arg2, self.arg3)
    }
}

struct A {}

impl MyTrait for A {}

fn main() {
    let a = A {};
    let x = a.handle_with_too_many_args(3, 2, 1);
    let y = a.handle_with_struct(HandleArgs::new().with_arg1(3).with_arg3(1));
    let z = a.handle_with_builder().with_arg1(3).with_arg3(1).finish();
    assert!(x == y && y == z);
}
```